# how can I calculate the multi-label top k precisions with tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multilabel-classification

My task is to predict the five most probable tags in a sentence. And now I've got unscaled logits from the output(dense connect) layer:

```
with tf.name_scope("output"):
    scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W,b, name="scores")
    predictions = tf.nn.top_k(self.scores, 5) # should be the k highest score
with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    labels = input_y  # its shape is (batch_size, num_classes)
    # calculate the top k accuracy
```

now predictions are just like [3,1,2,50,12] (3,1... are indexes of the highest scores), while labels are in "multi-hot" form: [0,1,0,1,1,0...].
 In python, i can simply write

```
correct_preds = [input_y[i]==1 for i in predictions]
weighted = np.dot(correct_preds, [5,4,3,2,1]) # weighted by rank 
recall  = sum(correct_preds) /sum(input_y)
precision =sum(correct_preds)/len(correct_preds)
```

but in tensorflow, what form shoud I use to complete this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

I've coded up an example of how to do the calculations.  All of the inputs in this example are coded as **tf.constant** but of course you can substitute your variables.

The main trick is the matrix multiplications.  First is **input_y** reshaped to be 2d times a [1x5] ones matrix called **to_top5**.  The second is **correct_preds** by the **weighted_matrix**.

## Code

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_y = tf.constant( [5,2,9,1] , dtype=tf.int32 )

predictions = tf.constant( [[9,3,5,2,1],[8,9,0,6,5],[1,9,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])

to_top5       = tf.constant( [[1,1,1,1,1]] , dtype=tf.int32 )
input_y_for_top5 = tf.matmul( tf.reshape(input_y,[-1,1]) , to_top5 )

correct_preds = tf.cast( tf.equal( input_y_for_top5 , predictions ) , dtype=tf.float16 )

weighted_matrix = tf.constant( [[5.],[4.],[3.],[2.],[1.]] , dtype=tf.float16 )

weighted = tf.matmul(correct_preds,weighted_matrix)

recall = tf.reduce_sum(correct_preds) / tf.cast( tf.reduce_sum(input_y) , tf.float16)
precision = tf.reduce_sum(correct_preds) / tf.constant(5.0,dtype=tf.float16)

## training
# Run tensorflow and print the result
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print "\n\n=============\n\n"
  print "\ninput_y_for_top5"
  print sess.run(input_y_for_top5)
  print "\ncorrect_preds"
  print sess.run(correct_preds)
  print "\nweighted"
  print sess.run(weighted)
  print "\nrecall"
  print sess.run(recall)
  print "\nprecision"
  print sess.run(precision)
  print "\n\n=============\n\n"
```

## Output

```
=============

input_y_for_top5
[[5 5 5 5 5]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [9 9 9 9 9]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]

correct_preds
[[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]

weighted
[[ 3.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 4.]
 [ 5.]]

recall
0.17651

precision
0.6001

=============
```

## Summary

The above examples shows a **batch** size of 4.

The first batch has a **y_label** of **5**, which means that the element with an index of 5 is the correct label for the first batch.  Furthermore, the **prediction** for the first batch is [9,3,5,2,1] which means that the **prediction** function thinks that the 9th element is the most likely, then element 3 is the next most likely and so on.

Let's say we want an example of a batch size of 3, then use the following code

```
input_y = tf.constant( [5,2,9] , dtype=tf.int32 )
predictions = tf.constant( [[9,3,5,2,1],[8,9,0,6,5],[1,9,3,4,5]])
```

If we substitute in the above lines to the program we can see that indeed it calculates everything for a batch size of 3 correctly.

Comment: it works when y_label is [1, num_classes], but when it comes to y_label in shape of [batch_size, num_classes] i.e. [[12,31,3],[1,33,41]], it seems not work..

Comment: You misunderstand.  I've updated the question to highlight that the code already handles variable batch sizes.

Comment: Inspired by your code and idea of using reshape and multiplication, I've made it by tensor flatten and tf.gather, much thanks !

Answer (score 1):

inspired by @wontonimo' answer above, I implemented a method using matrix ops and tf.reshape, tf.gather. The label tensor are "multi-hot", e.g. [[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1]]. prediction tensor are obtained by tf.nn.top_k, looks like [[3,1],[0,1]]. Here is the code:

```
top_k_pred = tf.nn.top_k(logits, 5)
tmp1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size)*num_classes, (-1,1))
idx_incre = top_k_pred[1] + tf.concat([tmp1]*5,1)
correct_preds = tf.gather(tf.reshape(y_label, (-1,), tf.reshape(idx_incre, (-1,)))
correct_preds = tf.reshape(correct_pred, (batch_size, 5))
weighted = correct_preds * [[5],[4],[3],[2],[1]]
```